# Solr MongoDB DataImportHandler Error

Tags: java, mongodb, solr

I am trying to import the MongoDB data into Solr for indexing, using [SolrMongoDataImportHandler](https://github.com/firemuzzy/SolrMongoImporter/tree/master/src/main/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport)

These are the lines which I added to my solrconfig.xml

```
<lib path="../../dist/solr-mongo-importer-1.0.0.jar" />  
<lib path="../../dist/mongo-2.9.3.jar" />   
<lib path="../../dist/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1" />
```

and the code for request handler

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

and this is my data-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
     <dataSource name="mymongo" type="MongoDataSource" database="cashlets" />
     <document name="service">
         <entity processor="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoEntityProcessor"
                 query="{'Active':1}"
                 collection="Service"
                 datasource="mymongo"
transformer="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoMapperTransformer" >

            <field column="name"    name="name"    mongoField="Name"/>

         </entity>
     </document>
 </dataConfig>
```

Now, when I try to do a full-import using **http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import**

I get the following response

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">2</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:45.486</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-11-26 16:21:30</str>
<str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
<str name="Rolledback">2012-11-26 16:21:30</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

and the following error in the logs.

> SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2 cannot be cast
>   ler.dataimport.MongoDataSource
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:264)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:375)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:445)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:205)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>           at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2 cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoD
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:621)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:327)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:225)
>           ... 24 more

In the logs, it says that it is trying to cast  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2 to org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoDBSource, but I am not able to find the reason why it is happening. All the configuration looks good. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Not sure on your error, but an alternative approach you could try using is [Mongo Connector](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector).

Comment: Thanks Stennie, already started using MongoConnector.